# Assembler, запись в поле данных со смещением

Tags: ассемблер

Стоит следующая задача, используя стандартный debug.exe:

> Записать код числа +10 в регистр ebx. Уменьшить его на 1. Скопировать его в регистр di. Записать +16 в поле данных со смещением, записанным в регистре si. Сложить содержимое регистра ebx с данными из поля данных и записать результат в поле данных. Очистить регистр si. Вернуться в ОС.

Если я правильно понял, в debug нельзя использовать регистры eax, ebx, ecx и т.д. Следовательно:

```
mov BX, A // помещаем значение 10 в регистр BX 
dec BX    // уменьшаем значение регистра на 1
mov DI,BX // копируем значение BX в DI
```

И вот далее возникает проблема, никак не могу понять как что либо в поле данных со смещением из SI. Значение SI после всех вышеописанных операций естественно не изменилось и равно 0000. Это означает что мне нужно просто записать значение 16 в SI? Сложить содержимое BX со значением из поля данным проблем вроде не должно составить, как и очистка регистра. Пытался разобраться с помощью учебника Степанова "Архитектура вычислительных систем и компьютерных сетей"

Comment: Я бы истолковал текст этой части задания буквально, т.е. написать инструкцию которая заносит значение по смещению в si. И не вдавался бы в подробности, что на этот момент в нем находиться. Да, это вполне может привести к обращению куда нибудь "не туда". (тем более, что никто не обещает что в si именно 0)

Comment: на счет некоего debug которым вы пользуетесь - видимо он 16 битный и 32 битных регистров не знает. стоит взять 32 битный ассемблер, если собираетесь выполнять этот код в 32 битном режиме

Comment: А можно попробовать чуть выйти за пределы задания и предварительно занести в si адрес какой нибудь переменной, я бы за это на месте препода не ругал, а хвалил. но кто его знает как у вас преподают ...